# Stop checkbox values being reset after page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I am working on a pop up window where the user can filter a table of data.

The filter is selected using checkboxes.

**My issue:**
On page load there is a `useEffect` that changes every checkbox to `false`. This is based on the props coming in from the API.

I'd like on page load (and when the filter opens) that the checkbox state is stored based on what the user has selected previously in their session

**code:**

**Filter component***

```
[...]
import FilterSection from "../FilterSection";

const Filter = ({
  open,
  handleClose,
  setFilterOptions,
  [..]
  roomNumbers,
}) => {
  const [roomValue, setRoomValue] = React.useState();

  const [roomListProp, setRoomListProp] = React.useState(); // e.g. [["roomone", false],        ["roomtwo", true]];

  const sendRoomFilterData = (checkedRoomsFilterData) => {
    setRoomValue(checkedRoomsFilterData);
  };

  const setCheckboxListPropRoom = (data) => {
    setRoomListProp(data);
  };

 // extract, convert to an object and pass back down? or set local storage and get
 // local storage and pass back down so that we can get it later?

   const convertToLocalStorageFilterObject = (roomData) => { // []
      if (roomData !== undefined) {
        const checkedRooms = roomData.reduce((a, curval) => ({ ...a, [curval[0]]: curval[1] }), {});
        localStorage.setItem("preserved", JSON.stringify(checkedRooms));  // sets in local   storage but values get wiped on page load.
      }
 };

React.useEffect(() => {
   const preservedFilterState = convertToLocalStorageFilterObject(roomListProp);
}, [roomListProp]); 

  const applyFilters = () => {
    setFilterOptions([roomValue]);
    handleClose();
  };

  const classes = CurrentBookingStyle();
  return (
    <Dialog
      fullWidth
      maxWidth="sm"
      open={open}
      onClose={() => handleClose(false)}
    >
      <DialogTitle>Filter By:</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent className={classes.margin}>
        <FilterSection
          filterName="Room number:"
          filterData={roomNumbers}
          setFilterOptions={sendRoomFilterData}
          setCheckboxListProp={setCheckboxListPropRoom}
        />
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={applyFilters}>
          Apply Filters
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

**Filter Section used in Filter**

```
import {
    TableCell,
    Typography,
    FormControlLabel,
    Checkbox,
    FormGroup,
} from "@material-ui/core";

const FilterSection = ({
    filterData, filterName, setFilterOptions, setCheckboxListProp
}) => {
    const [checkboxValue, setCheckboxValue] = React.useState({});

    const [checkboxFilterList, setCheckboxFilterList] = React.useState([]);

    const handleCheckboxChange = (event) => {
        setCheckboxValue({
            ...checkboxValue,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.checked, // room1: true
        });
    };

    const = () => filterData // ["room1" "room2"]; comes from API
        .filter((val) => !Object.keys(checkboxValue).includes(val))
        .reduce((acc, currval) => ({
            ...acc, [currval]: false, // converts array to object and sets values to false
        }), checkboxValue);


    React.useEffect(() => {
        const transformedCheckboxListItems = Object.entries(convertToObject());
        setCheckboxFilterList(transformedCheckboxListItems);
        setFilterOptions(transformedCheckboxListItems.filter(([, val]) => val).map(([key]) =>          key));
      setCheckboxListProp(transformedCheckboxListItems); 
     
    }, [checkboxValue]);
    return (
        <>
            <Typography style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{filterName}</Typography>
            <FormGroup row>
                {checkboxFilterList.map(([key, val]) => (
                    <TableCell style={{ border: 0 }}>
                        <FormControlLabel
                            control={(
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={val}
                                    onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                                    name={key}
                                    color="primary"
                                />
                            )}
                            label={key}
                        />
                    </TableCell>
                ))}
            </FormGroup>
        </>
    );
};
```

**What i have tried:**

I have created a reusable component called "FilterSection" which takes takes data from the API "filterData" and transforms it from an array to an object to set the initial state for the filter checkboxes.

On page load of the filter I would like the checkboxes to be true or false depending on what the user has selected, however this does not work as the `convertToObject` function in my `FilterSection` component converts everything to `false` again on page load. I want to be able to change this but not sure how? - with a conditional?

I have tried to do this by sending up the state for the selected checkboxes to the `Filter` component then setting the local storage, then the next step would be to get the local storage data and somehow use this to set the state before / after page load.  Unsure how to go about this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by moving this line:

```
 const [checkboxValue, setCheckboxValue] = React.useState({});
```

outside of the component it was in  because every time the component re-rendered it ran the function `(convertToObject()` which reset each checkbox to `false`

by moving the state for the checkboxes up three layers to the parent component, the state never got refreshed when the  or  component pop up closed. Now the checkbox data persists which is the result I wanted.

:D

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand it correctly, but let me have a go:

I have no idea what `convertToObject` does, but I assume it extracts the saved filters from localStorage and ... updates the filter value that has just been changed?

Each time the `FilterSection` renders for the first time, `checkboxValue` state is being initialised and an `useEffect` runs `setCheckboxListProp`, which clears the options, right?

If this is your problem, try running `setCheckboxListProp` directly in the `handleCheckboxChange` callback rather than in an `useEffect`. This will ensure it runs ONLY after the value is changed by manual action and not when the `checkboxValue` state is initialised.

Comment: Hello thank you for answering, @Khalt this is kind of right. The `convertToObject` function is the one that is called in the `useEffect` and clears the options (it turns each check value to false  them to `false`) every time the page loads, because this is what each checkbox should be on initial page load if the user hasn't selected anything.  On second page load and subsequent loads I'd like to keep the state that of the selected checkboxes.

Comment: `convertToObject` is there to take the initial data  / props passed into the component from a higher component which fetches the data from the API. This initial data is an `array` and I needed it to be an `object` so that i could feed the data into my checkboxes (as the checkbox component only accepts objects). I also at this point set all of the checkbox values to `false`